# How to re-type pointer to a class and be able to reach classes functions based on it's type?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a C++ code which should populate a screen (and it's behaviour) based on a function from the object pointer was initiated with. Let's better show it on a code:

```
class A:parentClass {
public:
    int X () {return 5;}
}

class B:parentClass {
public:
    int X () {return 3;}
}

class C:parentClass {
public:
    int X () {return 1;}
}

main {
    parentClass *p;
    p = new A;
    printf("%d\n,p.x); //to return 5
    delete p;
    p = new B;
    printf("%d\n,p.x); //to return 3
}
```

I'm getting something like this on compilation:

```
‘class parrentClass’ has no member named ‘x’
```

I know that this is wrong, as parrentClass simply doesn't have that member, but I don't have an idea how to solve this. I tried to go through templates, but I'm not getting anywhere.

I also tried to replace "parentClass *p;" with "int *p;", but then I'm getting:

```
cannot convert ‘CardsFrame*’ to ‘int*’
```

Thanks for your suggestions in advance,

Jan

Comment: This isn't your real code (if it is, there are ~200 things wrong with it). Please post the code you are actually compiling, and if it's too big, make an example program that will compile (except for the parts you are asking about).

Comment: Where is your declaration of class parentClass?

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare the `X()` method `virtual` on the parent class for this to work:

```
class ParentClass
{
    public:
        virtual int X();
};
```

To be clear: the following is a complete working example (compiled with gcc):

```
#include <iostream>

class ParentClass {
public:
    virtual int x() = 0;
};

class A : public ParentClass {
public:
    int x() { return 5; }
};

class B : public ParentClass {
public:
    int x() { return 3; }
};

class C : public ParentClass {
public:
    int x() { return 1; }
};

int main() {
    ParentClass *p;
    p = new A;
    std::cout << p->x() << std::endl; // prints 5
    delete p;
    p = new B;
    std::cout << p->x() << std::endl; // prints 3
    delete p;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort invested! That is what I was looking for!!!

I'm sorry to the others that my first code was rubbish, I'll try to compile my example first next time.
Jan

Answer (score 2):

You really need to get your basics right as your syntax is all wrong. You need to use `p->X()` to call the function. And to answer the actual question make `X()` `virtual` in the base class.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%d\n,p.x); //to return 5
```

should be:

```
printf("%d\n,p->X()); //to return 5
```

Also, `X()` should be virtual in the Base class.